# socket.io login system must refresh window

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am programming a simple login system. The user must introduce a nickname(no password needed). If the nickname is alredy chosen the user is told so(I used alert). If the nickname is free the user is told so. I am using express in the server. And socket.io in both the server and the client.
The thing is more or less working.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see it works. 
But if I introduced an invalid name the form gets disabled. I mean, if a want to send the nickname again I have to reload the page. 
Here is the code for the client:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

<script>

    var socket = io();

    var send_nickname =
    function()
    {

        socket.emit('msg', document.text_box.nickname.value);

        // check
        socket.on('login', function(msg){

            if(msg == 'ok')
            {
                //muy bien
                alert("You logged in as " + document.text_box.nickname.value);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("The nickname " + document.text_box.nickname.value + " is already chosen");
            }

        });

    };

</script>

<h1> Introduce your name </h1>

<form action="javascript:send_nickname()" name="text_box">
    nickname: <input type="text" name="nickname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is in the client but just in case... Here is the code for the server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var playerToSocket = {};
var socketToPlayer = {};

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  console.log('a user connected');

  var name = '';
  socket.on('msg', function(msg){

    // First of all, the client must choose a nick name
    if(name == ''){
        name = msg;

        if(playerToSocket[name] == null){

            // reserve the name
            playerToSocket[name] = socket;
            socketToPlayer[socket] = name;

            console.log("New player: " + name);

            // send on success
            socket.emit('login', 'ok');

        }
        else{

            console.log("The nickname is already chosen.");

            // send on fail
            socket.emit();
            socket.emit('login', 'fail');

        }

    }

  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){

    name = socketToPlayer[socket];
    console.log('user disconnected: ' + name);
    socketToPlayer[socket] = null;
    playerToSocket[name] = null;

  });

});

http.listen(5555, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:5555');
});
```

Comment: Instead of adding [solved] to your question, you can post how you did it in an answer below.

Comment: I was going to do it.